# jquery finding an Element with and ID as an ATTR?

Tags: jquery

Given the following:

```
<div" id="NAV">
 <ul>
  <li class="navitem " id="79">
   <span class="icon"> </span> Title
  </li>
  <li class="navitem " id="33">
   <span class="icon"> </span> Title
  </li>
  <li class="navitem " id="123">
   <span class="icon"> </span> Title
  </li>
  <li class="navitem " id="41">
   <span class="icon"> </span> Title
  </li>
  <li class="navitem " id="31">
   <span class="icon"> </span> Title
  </li>
  <li class="navitem " id="123">
   <span class="icon"> </span> Title
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

With jQuery how can I find the LI with an specific ID?

I tried this, but it removes everything?

```
$("#NAV li").attr("id", 74).remove();
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm only curious, but didn't it occur to you that you were *already*, with `$('#NAV')`, selecting an element with a specific `id` attribute?

Comment: $("#NAV li") selects all <li> beneath #NAV. attr("id", 74) then tries to set the id of every <li> to 74. You then remove all the <li>. Hence the behaviour that you're seeing. Mike Axiak has the correct syntax below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "#" selector:

```
$("#NAV li#74").remove();
```

I should say though that 74 is not a valid id value, as they have to start with a letter.

Comment: You're right about the invalid ID, but don't use a selector that specifies one ID descending from another. Since IDs must be unique, you should only need the targeted one. The tag name isn't necessary either. Both of these just slow down the selection.

Answer (score 1):

The others are correct in that numeric IDs are invalid in HTML4. But to select an element by its ID, you should only give the ID.

Instead of:

```
$('#NAV li#74')
```

you would do (if 74 was a valid ID):

```
$('#74')
```

Though you really should make it valid. Something like:

```
$('#item_74')
```

---

**EDIT:** If you were to use the approach you were taking, you could do something like this:

```
$("#NAV li").filter('[id=74]').remove();
```

This uses [the attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to filter the `<li>` elements down to the one where the ID attribute equals 74.

But again, why do that when you have a direct reference via ID, which gives you an extremely efficient selection.

Answer (score 0):

Pure-numeric ids are not allowed. And they must be unique.

You would do it like this though: `$('#NAV li#74')`.